# Detect end of Video with IMediaSeeking

Tags: c++, directx, directshow

I am playing a video to get some screens using DirectShow.

I am doing this in a loop by calling `IMediaControl->Run`, `IVMRWindowlessControl->GetCurrentImage` and then a `IMediaSeeking->SetPositions`.

The problem is that I cannot detect when the video is over. `IMediaSeeking->SetPositions` returns always same value (S_FALSE). `IMediaControl->Run`also returns always S_FALSE. I have also tried `IMediaEvent->GetEvent` after the call to `IMediaControl->Run` to check for `EC_COMPLETE` but instead returns (always) `EC_CLOCK_CHANGED`.

How can I detect the end of video ? Thanks

**UPDATE**: Doing something like

```
    long eventCode = 0;
    LONG_PTR ptrParam1 = 0;
    LONG_PTR ptrParam2 = 0;
    long timeoutMs = INFINITE;

    while (SUCCEEDED(pEvent->GetEvent(&eventCode, &ptrParam1, &ptrParam1, timeoutMs)))
    {
        if (eventCode == EC_COMPLETE) 
        {
            break;
        }

        // Free the event data.
        hr = pEvent->FreeEventParams(eventCode, ptrParam1, ptrParam1);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

blocks after few events: 0x53 (EC_VMR_RENDERDEVICE_SET), 0x0D (EC_CLOCK_CHANGED), 0x0E (EC_PAUSED), next call to GetEvent is blocking and the video is rendered (played frame by frame) in my `IVideoWindow`

Comment: Does the DirectShow event processing run on a separate thread?

Comment: Is on the same thread as the window for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing `IMediaEvent->GetEvent`, however note you will be receiving various events, not only `EC_CLOCK_CHANGED`. Keep receiving and you are to get `EC_COMPLETE`. [Step 6: Handle Graph Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN explains this in detail.

Comment: true, but enumerating Events seem to block. I have updated my question with some code.

Comment: It certainly blocks if you provide `INFINITE` timeout. That's why you need to look into MSDN on how to get notified on new event, using window message or event object.

Comment: I have noticed the INFINITE param, but I don't think an arbitrary value (ex:3000) is the right solution to this. So, I understand that enumerating values, like I do, is not the right approach, but instead I should register for an event (using wnd msg or object). From my point of view (this is my first contact with DirectShow) this is what I am doing by enumerating `IMediaEvent` object. Can you be more specific or provide a more exact location in msdn where I can find more info ? Thanks

Comment: So, I have found that I should register `pEvent->SetNotifyWindow(hWnd, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, 0);` And make the call to `IMediaEvent->GetEvent` on `WM_GRAPHNOTIFY`. Hope it;s the right track. Thanks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899506.aspx

Comment: You subscribe with `SetNotifyWindow` to see where new events are available. Having received this, you enumerate with `GetEvent` and zero timeout until you flush all pending events.

Comment: What about receiving notifications to an event object ? `IMediaEventEx` doesn't look like it can help. It's a different interface ?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the right path. With event object, you get a notification through a set event rather than a window message. You are still expected to fetch events the same way.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to avoid creating a new thread just to receive notifications (in my case one notification: `EC_COMPLETE`). Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the state of the filter graph with [IMediaControl::GetState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if it is stopped. You can also get the duration of the video from [IMediaSeeking::GetDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you may find helpful.

Another option is to use [event signaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This event processing can be off-threaded.